# Selenium can work but have a Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated

Tags: python

I am want to collect the all food title,so I use selenium to craw market website 
[market website](http://www.pxmart.com.tw/px/ingredients_search.px?list__01=&list__02=&list__search=)

this is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


chrome_path = "C:\selenium_driver_chrome\chromedriver.exe" 
web = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Administrator.SIN-20150824MHC\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\bin\phantomjs')
web.implicitly_wait(10)

web.get('http://www.pxmart.com.tw/px/ingredients_search.px')
time.sleep(1)

soup = BeautifulSoup(web.page_source,"lxml")
while len(soup.select('.ingredients-list-add')) > 0:
    for ele in soup.select('.paxmart-content'):
        print (ele.text)
    web.find_element_by_css_selector("div.ingredients-list-add > a").click()
    time.sleep(5)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(web.page_source,"lxml")
ele.to_excel('pxmart.xlsx')
web.close()
```

I need to use click to open more food title so I make the while if this way > 0
keep click to load page.[load button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSDTg.jpg)

but Here is the error message

```
ElementNotVisibleException                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-93794a560872> in <module>()
     15     for ele in soup.select('.paxmart-content'):
     16         print (ele.text)
---> 17     web.find_element_by_css_selector("div.ingredients-list-add > a").click()
     18     time.sleep(5)
     19     soup = BeautifulSoup(web.page_source,"lxml")

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py in click(self)
     75     def click(self):
     76         """Clicks the element."""
---> 77         self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
     78 
     79     def submit(self):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py in _execute(self, command, params)
    491             params = {}
    492         params['id'] = self._id
--> 493         return self._parent.execute(command, params)
    494 
    495     def find_element(self, by=By.ID, value=None):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    254         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    255         if response:
--> 256             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    257             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    258                 response.get('value', None))

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    192         elif exception_class == UnexpectedAlertPresentException and 'alert' in value:
    193             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, value['alert'].get('text'))
--> 194         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    195 
    196     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

ElementNotVisibleException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"81","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:55991","User-Agent":"Python http auth"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"id\": \":wdc:1497706043997\", \"sessionId\": \"b09d3cb0-5360-11e7-8b78-7dbb6382b171\"}","url":"/click","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"click","directory":"/","path":"/click","relative":"/click","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/click","queryKey":{},"chunks":["click"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/b09d3cb0-5360-11e7-8b78-7dbb6382b171/element/:wdc:1497706043997/click"}}
Screenshot: available via screen
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess was to update the implicit wait to use an explicit wait. However, I successfully ran your script locally and successfully.

I made sure to switch to virtualenv python3 and installed the latest chromedriver as well.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


chrome_path = "/Users/foo/Documents/Stackoverflow/question_1/chromedriver" 
web = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r'/Users/foo/Documents/Stackoverflow/question_1/phantomjs')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
web.explicity_wait(10)

web.get('http://www.pxmart.com.tw/px/ingredients_search.px')
time.sleep(1)

soup = BeautifulSoup(web.page_source,"lxml")
while len(soup.select('.ingredients-list-add')) > 0:
    for ele in soup.select('.paxmart-content'):
        print (ele.text)
    web.find_element_by_css_selector("div.ingredients-list-add > a").click()
    time.sleep(5)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(web.page_source,"lxml")
ele.to_excel('pxmart.xlsx')
web.close()
```

Example Output:
全聯美國牛胸腹雪花火鍋肉片
全聯澳洲牛肩里肌火鍋肉片
全聯澳洲牛肩里肌炒肉片
全聯澳洲牛肋條
全聯澳洲穀飼牛腱